# pure Javascript dynamic selector

Tags: javascript

In my html, only the first 4 elements can be deleted after clicking the "-" button, elements added to the list after entering them in the text box and clicking add do have "-" buttons but cannot be deleted after i click the "-" buttons

Only the 4 preset entries with buttons can be deleted by clicking their respective buttons. MY additional entries cannot. What could be done? How can I make the selector or the last function adapt dynamically to what elements I would add? Thanks

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var ul1 = document.getElementById("selection");
var ali = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var button2 = document.getElementsByClassName("del");

//var test = document.getElementById("deleteItem")


function inputLength(){
 return input.value.length;
}

// function createListElement(){
//  var li = document.createElement("li"); //creates                
//  var del = document.createElement("del");
//   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //adds what you have written (input.value) 
//   del.appendChild(document.createElement(button)); //adds a button
//   ul.appendChild(li); //adds a new <li></li> to the ul
//   input.value= '';                      
// }
function createListElement(){
 var li = document.createElement("li"); //creates                
 // var button = document.createElement("button");
 // button.innerHTML = "-";
 // li.appendchild(button);
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //adds what you have written (input.value) 
 var button = document.createElement("button");
 button.setAttribute("id", "deleteItem");
 button.setAttribute("class", "del");
 button.innerHTML = "-";
 li.appendChild(button);
 ul.appendChild(li); //adds a new <li></li> to the ul
 input.value='';                      
}


function addListAfterClick(){
 if (inputLength()>0){
  createListElement();
 }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event){
 if (inputLength()>0 && event.keyCode === 13){
  createListElement();
 }
}


button1.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

//1. If you click on the list item, it toggles the .done class on and off.
for (var i=0; i<ali.length; i++) {
  ali[i].addEventListener('click', doneOnClick);
 }

 function doneOnClick() {
  this.classList.toggle( 'done' );
 }

//2. Add buttons next to each list item to delete the item when
//   clicked on its corresponding delete button

 for (var i=0; i<button2.length; i++)
 {
  button2[i].addEventListener("click", delet);
 }

 function delet(){
  this.closest("li").remove();
 }


//3. BONUS: When adding a new list item, it automatically adds the delete button next to it. 

// var ul = document.getElementById("selection");
// var li = document.createElement("li");
// li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
// var button = document.createElement("button");
// button.innerHTML = "-";
// li.appendChild(button);
// li.setAttribute("id","element4");
// ul.appendChild(li);
// //alert(li.id);
```

```css
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow: 
    -1px -1px 0 firebrick,
    -2px -2px 0 firebrick,
    -3px -3px 0 firebrick,
    -4px -4px 0 firebrick,
    -5px -5px 0 firebrick,
    -6px -6px 0 firebrick,
    -7px -7px 0 firebrick,
    -8px -8px 0 firebrick,
    -30px 20px 40px dimgrey
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.deleteItem{
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript w DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>List</h1>
 <p id="onangona">test</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
 <button id="enter">Add</button>
 <ul id = "selection">
  <li class = "bold red" random="24">A<button id ='deleteItem' class = "del">-</button>
  </li>
  <li>B<button id ='deleteItem' class = "del">-</button>
  </li>
  <li>C<button id ='deleteItem' class = "del">-</button>
  </li>
  <li>D<button id ='deleteItem' class = "del">-</button>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to bind the event `addListener` inside `createElement()`?

Comment: @Ahmad, never thought of that, I would love to try that later once I get home. Thank you for your input

Comment: @Ahmad, thank you sir, found out i asked the wrong question- it now works as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your deletable elements first , then add without add buttons. Here is a working example

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , function(){
 create();
});

const selection = document.getElementById('selection');
const input = document.getElementById('userinput');

function create(){
    //Create default deletable values
 for(var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = 'Default-' + i
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = '-';
  addListener(button, li);
  li.appendChild(button);
  selection.appendChild(li);
 } 
}

enter.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = userinput.value;
  li.className = 'inline';
  input.value = '';
  selection.appendChild(li);
});

function addListener(button, li) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    li.remove();
    button.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
<button id="enter">Add</button>
<ul id="selection">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. however what I want to happen is that whenever a new element is created, a (-) button would follow right after it, and make it a removable content just like the first 4 entries...

Answer (score 0):

answered by @Ahmad

> Did you try to bind the event addListener inside createElement()?

I did and it now works smoothly. Thanks